# what is the difference between print @array and print "@array" in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Consider the below code for example:

```
@array=(1..10);
print @array;
print "@array";

The output is as follows:
12345678910
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Well, that's your difference right there :-)

Comment: you can see the difference there itself.... :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a question about string conversion and interpolation. In perl, `"` is treated differently to `'`, in that perl is asked to interpolate any variables in the string.

That's why:

```
my $str = "fish";
print "This is a $str\n";
```

Works. (With single quotes, it wouldn't). But for things that aren't strings, perl applies some conversion rules. Pretty basic for most cases - a numeric value gets turned into the string equivalent (in base 10). So:

```
my $num = 10;
print "The number is $num\n";
```

"just works" rather than forcing you to use `printf`/`sprintf` to format convert a numeric value to an appropriate representation.

So the reason you get your first result is that `print` takes a list of arguments.

So `print @array` is actually `print 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;`.

That gives you the result, because you haven't specified a separator to your `print`. (You can do this by setting `$,` - see below)

However `"@array"` is using `@array` in an explicitly stringified context, and so first it unpacks the array and space separates it.

This behaviour is controlled by the special variable `$"`. You can read about this in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
$" = ":";
print "@array";
```

See also: [Interpolating Arrays into Strings](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch03_05.htm)

You can also 'tell' print to separate the values it's got, using `$,`. By default, it's not set (e.g. is undef - see also perlvar) - so you get your first behaviour.

But you could:

```
$, = ",";
print @array;
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I was just going to write. But I think I would have mentioned `$,` as well as `$"`.

Comment: Ah good point. I'll add that in.

Comment: *"With single quotes, it wouldn't"* That's dangerously close to the awful *"it doesn't work"*!